# add element in array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, taxonomy

I have this code :

```
if($pf_categorynotin){
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $pf_categorynotin,
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    ); //category__in
}
```

It has  one taxonomy defined which is **portfolio_tag**. 
What I want to do is to add another taxonomy like  **portfolio_tag**

I'm not sure if will work like this: `'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_category', 'portfolio_tags',`

Basically what I want to do is add also another taxonomy in that array.

Comment: You should edit your question to explain that this array will be use as param for WP_Query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want more than one value you have to use an array, so replace your following line:

```
'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_category',
```

for this one:

```
'taxonomy' => array('portfolio_category','portfolio_tags'),
```

but remember that the code that reads `$args['tax_query']` will have to be adapted to take into account that `$args['tax_query'][0]['taxonomy']` could now be an array or a string.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at "*Multiple Taxonomy Handling*" example here :
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

```
$args['tax_query'] => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $pf_categorynotin,
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_tags',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $pf_categorynotin,
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    )
);
```

You should adapt `relation` and `operator` to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an array out of `taxonomy` so your code would look like:

```
if($pf_categorynotin){
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => array('portfolio_category', 'portfolio_tags'),
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $pf_categorynotin,
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    ); //category__in
}
```

and than `$args['tax_query'][0]['taxonomy'][0]` will be `'portfolio_category'` and `$args['tax_query'][0]['taxonomy'][1]` will be `'portfolio_tags'`

Answer (score 0):

```
if($pf_categorynotin){
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => array('portfolio_category','portfolio_tags'),
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $pf_categorynotin,
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    ); //category__in
}
```

could do the trick

Answer (score 0):

taxonomy needs to be another array for example:

```
$taxonomy = array(tax1, tax2, tax3);
```

then you add

```
array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $pf_categorynotin,
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
```